# How to create a top level object with no fields or methods in Golang?

Tags: go

Since I am from Java and new to Golang, I will try to explain what I want in Java.

```
    interface Car { }

    class MyCarA implements Car {
      int specificToA
    }

    class MyCarB implements Car {
      int specificToB
    }
```

I think such an interface (like Car) is called a marker interface in Java. It is just to indicate the compiler the necessary abstraction.

How can I do this in Golang ?

I have

```
type MyCarA struct {
   specificToA int
}
type MyCarB struct {
  specificToB int
}
```

How can I generalise these structs now ? Should it be an interface or another struct ?

Comment: Don't try classical OOP in Go: You will hurt yourself and your code will be a complicated, ugly mess. Also this sounds like a XY question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: A type implements an interface by implementing its methods. There is no explicit declaration of intent, no "implements" keyword. [https://tour.golang.org/methods/10]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
type Car interface { IAmACar() }

type MyCarA struct {
  specificToA int
}
func (MyCarA) IAmACar() {}

type MyCarB struct {
  specificToB int
}
func (MyCarB) IAmACar() {}
```

You test for the marker using a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
_, itIsACar := v.(Car)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/J0rfOjztAV)

The Car interface can also be used to detect errors statically:

```
var c Car
c = MyCarA{0} // ok
c = 0 // error, int is not a car
```

The [go/ast](http://godoc.org/go/ast) package does something similar. See uses of the function [exprNode](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b3301865a025fda72b8d327fad4461bb7bf68600/src/go/ast/ast.go#L488-L489) in the file [ast.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go).

Answer (score 0):

The above method is correct & works for runtime detection, but it won't provide compile time detection. If you want compile time detection, pass the type to a function which takes the interface as an argument and check. See sample below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyType struct {
    a int
    b int
}

type NotMyType struct {
    a int
    b int
}

type Printer interface {
    Print(a string) error
}

func (m *MyType) Print(s string) error {
    fmt.Println(m.a, m.b, s)
    return nil
}

//Uncomment following function to see compilation work
// func (m *NotMyType) Print(s string) error {
//  fmt.Println(m.a, m.b, s)
//  return nil
// }

func main() {
    t := &MyType{
        a: 1, b: 2,
    }

    t1 := &NotMyType{
        a: 1, b: 2,
    }

    checkPrintable(t)
    checkPrintable(t1)
}

func checkPrintable(p Printer) {
    p.Print("Test message")
}
```

To make it work you need to uncomment the Print function for NotMyType.

Hope this helps.