# Is it possible to leave the type of the parameter of an interface to the receiver which implements it in Go?

Tags: go, types, interface

Basically I want to have an interface which has a `SetParams` method, the declaration of which declares it receives one parameter, and the return type of the method, but leaves the return type of the parameter up to the receiver.

Something like this interface:

```
type ParamsInterface interface {
    SetParams(<someType>) ParamsInterface
}
```

Now, when `XStruct` implements it, the type of the parameters is `XParams`

```
type XStruct struct {
    params XParams
}

func (x *XStruct) SetParams(params *XParams) ParamsInterface {
    x.params = params
    return x
}
```

But when `YStruct` implements it, the type of the parameters is `YParams`

```
type YStruct struct {
    params YParams
}

func (y *YStruct) SetParams(params *YParams) ParamsInterface {
    y.params = params
    return y
}
```

Comment: No this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is called generics, you can only use empty interface `interface{}` and 
type casting.

This is doc about generics in go: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vrAy9gMpMoS3uaVphB32uVXX4pi-HnNjkMEgyAHX4N4/edit#.

This also can help you:

[How is the empty interface different than a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171642/how-is-the-empty-interface-different-than-a-generic)

[Why no generics in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912089/why-no-generics-in-go)

This article suggests some ways how to live without generics: https://appliedgo.net/generics/

Here you can find code generator for generics (in my honest opinion that's not the best idea) https://github.com/cheekybits/genny.

Comment: But if I use empty interface, will it won't give the autocomplete suggestions from `YParams` and `XParams` will it?

Comment: @AyushGupta I updated the answer, check last two links

Comment: hmm, if I go without generics i'll have to create a Stub got a particular method for XParams

Comment: @AyushGupta didn't understand you

Comment: If I do create a specific type as input , say 'CommonParams', I'll have to accept a key as input in XStruct, but not do anything with it, and use it in YStruct

Comment: You can use switch and type casting for that or create CommonParams as interface with some methods, instead of struct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159473/discussion-between-anton-shkurenko-and-ayush-gupta).

Comment: Note that there is no type “casting” in Go. You have “type conversions” and “type assertions”, which are both quite different.